# Error when no constructor method and error when constructor method

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, tableview

im having a problem with my tableview. whenever i add a item to my database, it appears on my tableview, but only after i close and reopen the tableview. However i'd like to have added to my tableview immediately after having it added. So i made a refresh method, but im getting error from there. I have added comments to my code, which explains where the problem occurs.

I have removed imports and @FXML tags

```
package packet;



public class DataControll implements Initializable {



    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stat;
    private PreparedStatement prep;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    private ObservableList<Toidubaas> toidudata;

    public void eemaldaListist() {

    }

    public void lisaNupp(ActionEvent event) {

        try {
            String query = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Toiduinfo (Toidu, Kalorid, Valgud, Süsivesikud, Rasvad) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            prep = con.prepareStatement(query);

            prep.setString(1, lisaToit.getText());
            prep.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(lisaKcal.getText()));
            prep.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(lisaValk.getText()));
            prep.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(lisaSysi.getText()));
            prep.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(lisaRasv.getText()));
            prep.execute();
            prep.close();
        } catch (Exception er) {
            System.out.println(er.getMessage());
        }

        clearForm();
    }

    private void clearForm() {
        lisaToit.clear();
        lisaKcal.clear();
        lisaValk.clear();
        lisaSysi.clear();
        lisaRasv.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        toidudata = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        tbCal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Toidubaas, Integer>("rbCal"));
        tbProt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Toidubaas, Integer>("rbProt"));
        tbCarb.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Toidubaas, Integer>("rbCarb"));
        tbFat.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Toidubaas, Integer>("rbFat"));
        tbMeal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Toidubaas, String>("rbMeal"));



        try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Fooditabel.sqlite");
            stat = con.createStatement();
            stat.executeUpdate(
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Toiduinfo (Toidu TEXT, Kalorid INTEGER, Valgud INTEGER, Süsivesikud INTEGER, Rasvad INTEGER)");

            ResultSet rs = con.createStatement()
                    .executeQuery("SELECT Toidu, Kalorid, Valgud, Süsivesikud, Rasvad FROM Toiduinfo");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Toidubaas nt = new Toidubaas(); //if i add constructor method, im getting error here, saying the constructor is undefined

                nt.rbMeal.set(rs.getString("Toidu"));
                nt.rbCal.set(rs.getInt("Kalorid"));
                nt.rbProt.set(rs.getInt("Valgud"));
                nt.rbCarb.set(rs.getInt("Süsivesikud"));
                nt.rbFat.set(rs.getInt("Rasvad"));
                toidudata.add(nt);
            }

            tbTabelview.setItems(toidudata);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ;
        }
    }

    public void refreshTable() {
        toidudata.clear();
        try {
            String query = "Select * FROM Toiduinfo";
            prep = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = prep.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                toidudata.add(new Toidubaas(     //Getting error here, if im not using constructor method, saying the method is undefined.
                   rs.getString("Toidu"),
                   rs.getInt("Kalorid"), 
                   rs.getInt("Valgud"),
                   rs.getInt("Süsivesikud"), 
                   rs.getInt("Rasvad")));
                tbTabelview.setItems(toidudata);
            }
            prep.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {

        }
    }
}
```

and here is the class with constructor method. Please note that constructor method is commented out, so my program would populate tableview with database data.

```
public class Toidubaas {

    public  SimpleIntegerProperty rbCal = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public  SimpleIntegerProperty rbProt = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public  SimpleIntegerProperty rbCarb = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public  SimpleIntegerProperty rbFat = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public  SimpleStringProperty rbMeal = new SimpleStringProperty();

//This is the constructor method

      /*public Toidubaas(String sbMeal, Integer sbCal, Integer sbProt, Integer sbCarb, Integer sbFat) {

        this.rbMeal = new SimpleStringProperty(sbMeal);
        this.rbCal = new SimpleIntegerProperty(sbCal);
        this.rbProt = new SimpleIntegerProperty(sbProt);
        this.rbCarb = new SimpleIntegerProperty(sbCarb);
        this.rbFat = new SimpleIntegerProperty(sbFat);

    }*/

    public String getRbMeal() {
        return rbMeal.get();
    }

    public void setRbMeal(String v) {
        rbMeal.set(v);
    }

    public Integer getRbCal() {
        return rbCal.get();
    }

    public void setRbCal(Integer v) {
        rbCal.set(v);
    }

    public Integer getRbProt() {
        return rbProt.get();
    }

    public void setRbProt(Integer v) {
        rbProt.set(v);
    }

    public Integer getRbCarb() {
        return rbCarb.get();
    }

    public void setRbCarb(Integer v) {
        rbCarb.set(v);
    }

    public Integer getRbFat() {
        return rbFat.get();
    }

    public void setRbFat(Integer v) {
        rbFat.set(v);
    }



}
```

Comment: create a 2nd constructor which you don't pass any values like this : `public Toidubaas(){}`

Comment: "but im getting error from there" - So what would that error be? Compile-time? Exception? What does the error message say?

Comment: Notice that, as @XtremeBaumer said, you can have more than one constructor in each class, as long as they have sufficiently different parameters. Just declare them as you need and use either one of them as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. Didnt know i could have more than one constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really confusing what you're asking here.  I'd recommend posting the actual error text rather than leaving in-code comments.

So you're attempting to use `Toidubaas` in two separate ways:

**First (Empty Constructor)**

```
Toidubaas nt = new Toidubaas(); //if i add constructor method, im getting error here, saying the constructor is undefined

nt.rbMeal.set(rs.getString("Toidu"));
nt.rbCal.set(rs.getInt("Kalorid"));
nt.rbProt.set(rs.getInt("Valgud"));
nt.rbCarb.set(rs.getInt("Süsivesikud"));
nt.rbFat.set(rs.getInt("Rasvad"));
toidudata.add(nt);
```

**Second (Parameterized Constructor)**

```
toidudata.add(new Toidubaas(     //Getting error here, if im not using constructor method, saying the method is undefined.
rs.getString("Toidu"),
rs.getInt("Kalorid"), 
rs.getInt("Valgud"),
rs.getInt("Süsivesikud"), 
rs.getInt("Rasvad")));
tbTabelview.setItems(toidudata);
```

There's two ways to handle this: either standardize how you access this (IE: change the code in first to second, or vica versa), or support both methods.

**Toidubaas**

```
public class Toidubaas {

    public  SimpleIntegerProperty rbCal = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public  SimpleIntegerProperty rbProt = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public  SimpleIntegerProperty rbCarb = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public  SimpleIntegerProperty rbFat = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public  SimpleStringProperty rbMeal = new SimpleStringProperty();

    //Empty Constructor (only need this if standardized to first approach)
    public Toidubaas() {}

    //Parameterized Constructor (only need this if standardized to second approach) 
    public Toidubaas(String sbMeal, Integer sbCal, Integer sbProt, Integer sbCarb, Integer sbFat) {

        rbMeal.set(sbMeal);
        rbCal.set(sbCal);
        rbProt.set(sbProt);
        rbCarb.set(sbCarb);
        rbFat.set(sbFat);    
    }

    //Getters/Setters
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to add a constructor with parameters, set the values one by one by calling the setters. It's also possible to overload the constructor (you shouldn't create the properties more than once though).

The row is not added to the `TableView`, since you never add it in case you submit the data successfully, which is pretty simple to fix though:

```
String query = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Toiduinfo (Toidu, Kalorid, Valgud, Süsivesikud, Rasvad) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
    String toidu = lisaToit.getText();
    int kalorid = Integer.parseInt(lisaKcal.getText());
    int valgud = Integer.parseInt(lisaValk.getText());
    int süsivesikud = Integer.parseInt(lisaSysi.getText());
    int rasvad = Integer.parseInt(lisaRasv.getText());

    prep.setString(1, toidu);
    prep.setInt(2, kalorid);
    prep.setInt(3, valgud);
    prep.setInt(4, süsivesikud);
    prep.setInt(5, rasvad);

    if (prep.executeUpdate() > 0) {
        // object filled with data from input data
        Toidubaas newToidubaas = new Toidubaas(toidu,
                                               kalorid,
                                               valgud,
                                               süsivesikud,
                                               rasvad);

        // add new item to table here
        toidudata.add(newToidubaas);
    }
    clearForm();
} catch (Exception er) {
    System.out.println(er.getMessage());
}
```